# How can I wrap text nodes separated by <br><Br> with their own <p> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

I've got content coming back from a webservice I cannot modify that returns data such as:

```
<div id="entrance" style="">
    Habilitação / Diploma de Ensino Medio Diploma de Ensino Pre Universitario 
    <br>
    <br>
    Diploma Record of study 
</div>
```

How can I wrap the two sentences in separate < p > tags using jQuery? I know I could use .wrap but that would wrap the entire contents. Do I need a RegEx?

Thanks,
Thomas

UPDATE:

My requirements changed to needing a list instead of paragraphs so using the answer below, I modified it slightly to wrap in < li > and then the whole thing in a < ul >

```
jQuery('#entrance').show();
jQuery('#entrance').html(data).contents().each(function () {
if ( this.nodeType === 3 ) jQuery( this ).wrap( '<li />' );
    else jQuery( this ).remove();
});
jQuery('#entrance').wrapInner('<ul />');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
$( '#entrance' ).contents().each(function () {
    if ( this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim( this.data ) !== '' ) {
        $( this ).wrap( '<p />' );
    } else {
        $( this ).remove();
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZMD6m/5/

My code transforms all non-empty text-nodes to paragraphs containing that text. All other types of nodes are removed.

Comment: Only drawback: your code also creates a paragraph out of the linebreak between the `<br>` tags.

Comment: @Blazemonger Ah yes. I thought it didn't, since I didn't see it in my demo. I'll fix that...

Comment: Thanks, I was just investigating using replaceWith(). Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, I did modify it to use a list though. See updated question if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses `$(this).text()` to find the length of each sub-element. If it's zero, it's removed, otherwise it's wrapped in a paragraph:

```
$('#entrance').contents().each(function(i,el) {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()).length) {
        $(this).wrap('<p>');
    } else {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ZMD6m/3/

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I'm using a modified version of the answer above though, since my requirement changed to needing a list instead of paragraphs.